# StyleCop rule for having empty line before constructor

Tags: c#, stylecop

In C# code we are using StyleCop.Analyzers and IMHO all rules regarding formatting are default. Today at Code Review I spotted a place

```
private readonly double _height;
public CalculationEngine(
    height,
```

But I would like it to be:

```
private readonly double _height;

public CalculationEngine(
    height,
```

Is there a rule for having an empty line before constructor like in this situation?

Comment: Would SA1516: ElementsMustBeSeparatedByBlankLine help? It's not specifically for constructors, though.

Comment: @HansKesting indeed it works for this situation but it also forces me to place empty lines between each property and I don't want to do that.